# How to share the image in the application as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, ane

I am using the [**Android-Sharing-Extension-ANE**](https://github.com/illuzor/Android-Sharing-Extension-ANE/blob/master/README.md).

How to share an image as result from my application code?

This code does not work

```css
var bitmap:Bitmap = ...;

// encoding image by native encoder (availible on FP 11.3/AIR 3.3 or newer)
var bitmapBytes:ByteArray = bitmap.bitmapData.encode(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height), new JPEGEncoderOptions(70)));

var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("image_for_share.jpg");

var stream:FileStream = new FileStream(); // write file to local memory
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeBytes(fileBytes);
stream.close();

SharingExtension.shareImage(file, "Choser title", "Message"));
```

Comment: You encode image to **bitmapBytes**, but write **fileBytes**. Different variables.

Comment: how do I share an image with this ANE I use animate cc?

Comment: You say _"This code does not work"_ but the solution is hinted by the **error** message that you never copy/paste here. Tell us your compiler error(s) for a faster Answer.

Answer (score 0):

> *"How do I share an image with this ANE I use Animate CC?"*

From the "Read Me" of that ANE:

> **How to use:**
>
> - Connect `com.illuzor.extensions.SharingExtension.ane` file to your
>     Android AIR project.
> - Import `com.illuzor.sharingextension.SharingExtension;`

Since it's not clear what your exact problem is (because not enough information given)...

(1) Did you **import** the required Class files?

```
import com.illuzor.sharingextension.SharingExtension; 


btn_Share.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, shareAndroid); 


function shareAndroid (event: MouseEvent): void 
{
    //# If this works then replace with bitmap code (use shareImage)
    SharingExtension.shareText ("AS3 Test", "This text is from AS3 code"); 

}
```

(2) Did you add (connect) the ANE to your project (in Settings)?

Read this for advise on adding an ANE: 
https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/using-ane-in-flash.html

Comment: Share text code works
 SharingExtension.shareText ("AS3 Test", "This text is from AS3 code"); 

 Share image code does not work
SharingExtension.shareImage(file, "Choser title", "Message");

Comment: If you're serious about getting some help, you have to **give your helpers some useful info**. You tell me _"code does not work"_ so maybe stop using it if you downloaded a broken library code.... But I think it's not broken. Just you are not telling us what happens when you try to compile an APK. Does it compile successfully? Is your `File` pointing to a working image file? Can you successfully open same image file (`image_for_share.jpg` on device) with other programs?